# Table type variable add value in loop

Tags: oracle, loops, types

I created table type

```
 create or replace TYPE NUMBER_ARRAY 
    AS TABLE OF NUMBER;
```

I want `PERIODS` variable add value in loop

```
DECLARE PERIODS NUMBER_ARRAY;
BEGIN
FOR I IN 1..10
LOOP
--I add to periods
END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you look something like

```
DECLARE 
  PERIODS NUMBER_ARRAY := NUMBER_ARRAY();
BEGIN
  FOR I IN 1..10 LOOP
    periods.extend;
    periods(i) := i * 2;
  END LOOP;
END;
```